# BTC transaction issues

Tags: blockchain.info

Respectfully requesting to look into this transaction. Did it got confirmed or not? is been 5 days now.
Thanks
18MJieFJcDiFbAsvSxe5iCaBAYsikgJta6

Comment: Enter your address to a service like chain.so or blockchain.info to check the transaction status.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too narrow

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify any transaction id so we can't look into the transaction.

You can see however, that this bitcoin address has received bitcoins, and they have been spent again.

You can see the transactions of any bitcoin on a block explorer such as blocktrail:

https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/address/18MJieFJcDiFbAsvSxe5iCaBAYsikgJta6